# Windows always updates python 3.9.0 to 3.9.13

Tags: python, windows

I manually installed Python 3.9.0 in my specified folder. However, Windows always updated it to 3.9.13 overnight, and installed into C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39. How can I prevent it?

I tried reinstalling Python 3.9.0. But Windows always upgraded it for me.

Comment: how you install python 3.9.0?

Comment: I downloaded install package from: https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/

Comment: you need to learn how to manage different python envs. like conda, venv

Comment: That's unrelated to this question.

Comment: Taking a glance at this [discussion](https://discuss.python.org/t/stop-auto-upgrading-python-version/32728), I'd ask the same question: is it your personal PC or managed by an IT department?